# como fazer uma animação abrir e fechar antes de exibir o site?

Tags: javascript, iframe, animação

boa tarde galera, estou com uma dulvida para incrementar uma animação (banner) feita no Google Web Designer. Gostaria de saber como poderia executar um iframe, chamando a animação, fechar ele assim que a animação acabar e depois disso carregar a pagina inicial do site? No caso teria que fazer isso usando JS?

Comment: Voce pode usar jquery para mostrar primiero essa animação antes de tudo.

Comment: no caso fazer uma função usando load para carregar, um stop pra parar e carregando a pagina depois? tentei ler meio por cima as funções do jquery mas não entendi direito

Comment: pera ai montar antes de tudo? vc diz fazer a animação? pq eu ja fiz ela no Google Web Designer só gostaria de saber como eu poderia abrir, executar e fechar antes ou enquanto carrega a pagina inicial do  meu site. no caso a animação o GWD salva em html mas feito com JS